# Access token signature validation failing while invoking Microsoft Identity Platform

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, jwt, auth0, microsoft-identity-platform

I am using auth0 and trying to validate Signature by invoking Microsoft identity platform but I'm receiving the error below while invoking the verify method. Please also find my code snippet.

Code Snippet:

```
  try {
        DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.decode(accessToken); // your string
        JwkProvider provider =  new JwkProviderBuilder(new URL("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tid/discovery/v2.0/keys")).build();
        Jwk jwk = provider.get(decodedJWT.getKeyId());
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);
        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                                  .withIssuer("auth0")
                                  .build();
       
        
        verifier.verify(decodedJWT);
        

    } catch (JWTVerificationException | JwkException | MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error

> com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.SignatureVerificationException: The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: SHA256withRSA
> at com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.RSAAlgorithm.verify(RSAAlgorithm.java:50)
> at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.verify(JWTVerifier.java:299)
> at com.identity.telsmsidentity.util.MSTokenValidator.validateMSToken(MSTokenValidator.java:43)
> at com.identity.telsmsidentity.controller.TelsPageController.validateToken(TelsPageController.java:98)
> at com.identity.telsmsidentity.controller.TelsPageController.getUserInfoFromGraph(TelsPageController.java:59)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)

Comment: Is your token issued by Auth0 or by Azure AD?

Comment: This token is issued by Azure AD but getting the same error even if I am providing issuer as Azure AD. not sure if I am providing correct information.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me, pls make sure your token version and use the corresponding version:

```
String token = "";
String tenantID = "";
// For Azure AD V1 token
String providerURLV1 = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID + "/discovery/keys";
String issuerV1 = "https://sts.windows.net/" + tenantID + "/";
// For Azure AD V2 token
String providerURLV2 = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID + "/discovery/v2.0/keys";
String issuerV2 = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID + "/v2.0";

try {
    DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.decode(token);
    JwkProvider provider = new JwkProviderBuilder(new URL(providerURLV1)).build();
    Jwk jwk = provider.get(decodedJWT.getKeyId());
    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);
    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).withIssuer(issuerV1).build();

    System.out.println(verifier.verify(decodedJWT).getClaims());

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @Aryansh glad to help ：）

Comment: Hi @ Stanley, my apologies, Still getting the same error. Please note that I am using V1 version. Cant figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: @ Stanley ,one thing I noticed that cant access issuer URL from browser.

Comment: It is by design, issuer URL is not for access from a browser. Could you pls provide more error details by `catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}`?

Comment: `com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.SignatureVerificationException: The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: SHA256withRSA
 at com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.RSAAlgorithm.verify(RSAAlgorithm.java:50)
 at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.verify(JWTVerifier.java:299)
 at com.identity.telsmsidentity.util.MSTokenValidator.validateSignature(MSTokenValidator.java:41)
 at com.identity.telsmsidentity.util.MSTokenValidator.validateMSToken(MSTokenValidator.java:21)
 at com.identity.telsmsidentity.controller.TelsPageController.getUserInfoFromGraph
   `

Comment: @ Stanley , When invoking graph API with this token getting the response. I have absolutely no clue why I am getting the error while validating this token.

Comment: @Aryansh, tokens for Microsoft graph API are signed differently from other access tokens. Users can't and no need to verify them just trust and use them directly, they will be and only could be verified by Microsoft Graph Service.

Comment: @Aryansh, this is the official doc about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

**Microsoft-developed APIs like Microsoft Graph or APIs in Azure have additional proprietary token formats. These proprietary formats might be encrypted tokens, JWTs, or special JWT-like tokens that will not validate.

Clients must treat access tokens as opaque strings because the contents of the token are intended for the resource (the API) only**  Pls accept my answer if it is helpful :)

Comment: @Aryansh how's going? Do you have any more concerns ?

Comment: @Aryansh, I am sorry I have no google meet and I am in company, it is not allowed to do so :(, you can just ask your questions here

Comment: Hi @ Stanley, I am building an user management system by using spring boot and MS Identity platform.
Both Authorization and Authentication will be done by MSIP. My application will responsible for creating
approles, groups, assigning user to groups or role etc will be done programmatically by calling graph API.

Comment: Any client application wants create groups roles etc have to call my application where I need to validate their access token 
they have sent after they have authenticated themselves with MS Identity platform. There I have the requirement of validating 
their access token and need to decode the token to get claims. This is my requirement.

Comment: @Aryansh, I see, if the token that users obtained from MSIP is for calling your application, in your application logic you need to validate it. If the token is obtained for calling Microsoft Graph API, you need not validate it, the validation process will be done by Microsoft Graph service, when users call Microsoft Graph API

Comment: @ Stanley, User authenticated through MSIP and received ID_TOKEN and Access Token. Then he sends both id and access token to my application. I am able to validate id token signature but not able to validate access token signature. The above error is occurring when I am doing the signature validation on access token but I am able to validate id Token signature .

Comment: @Aryansh, may  I know how you get this access token? Could you pls share your request ?

Comment: Hi @ Stanley,  I get Access token through AAD sso authentication. Please let me know if you need more details ?

Comment: @Aryansh, may I know its scope?

Comment: I was building on top the autogenerated springboot from application names "msal-web-sample" MSIP. Just debugged the code. they are passing null in the scope.

Comment: If the scope is null, Azure AD will consider you are requesting for Microsoft graph API token. Could you pls  check `aud` claim in https://jwt.io/?